# bamboo 6.2.2 plan specification as code failure which works with 6.0.2

Tags: specifications, bamboo

### Bamboo 6.2.2 plan specification as code failure which works with 6.0.2

With the recent upgrade on the Bamboo Server from 6.0.2 to 6.2. Upgraded the Bamboo Specification library with the latest 6.2.2. Compilation of the same code works fine. But failure when execute with the following errors.

```
2017-10-26 23:26:24,723 INFO [BambooPlanSpecRefactor] Publishing null
2017-10-26 23:26:24,733 INFO [BambooServer] Publishing plan ASSIST-CLASSROOM4
2017-10-26 23:26:28,261 INFO [BambooServer] An error occurred while publishing plan ASSIST-CLASSROOM4: Could not parse yaml input: Cannot create property=rootEntity for JavaBean=com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.util.BambooSpecProperties@5ec47362
in 'string', line 1, column 5:
--- !!com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.uti ... 
    ^
Cannot create property=pluginConfigurations for JavaBean=com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.model.plan.PlanProperties@ca60880
in 'string', line 2, column 13:
rootEntity: !!com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api ... 
            ^
Unable to find property 'pluginConfigurations' on class: com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.model.plan.PlanProperties
in 'string', line 9, column 25:
  pluginConfigurations: []
                        ^

in 'string', line 2, column 13:
rootEntity: !!com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api ... 
            ^

2017-10-26 23:26:28,262 INFO [BambooServer] (for more information, enable more detailed logging with system property -Dbamboo.specs.log.level=DEBUG)
An error occurred while publishing plan ASSIST-CLASSROOM4: Could not parse yaml input: Cannot create property=rootEntity for JavaBean=com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.util.BambooSpecProperties@5ec47362
in 'string', line 1, column 5:
--- !!com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.uti ... 
    ^
Cannot create property=pluginConfigurations for JavaBean=com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.model.plan.PlanProperties@ca60880
in 'string', line 2, column 13:
rootEntity: !!com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api ... 
            ^
Unable to find property 'pluginConfigurations' on class: com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api.model.plan.PlanProperties
in 'string', line 9, column 25:
  pluginConfigurations: []
                        ^

in 'string', line 2, column 13:
rootEntity: !!com.atlassian.bamboo.specs.api ... 
            ^

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64951', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0`
```

Comment: I think I figured out that I am using a newer version of Bamboo configuration spec as code.

Comment: Could you confirm the Bamboo version ? 
Probably you need to match the bamboo version and the Bamboo-specs version